# How to remove div contents

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to refresh the content of a div tag.  I create a map using Openlayer3. In my web there is a button to render a map into a div tag but every time I clicked the button another map is created following the last map.  The goal is to remove the map showed showed into the div and render the new one.  How can I do that ?

I tried

```
$('map').empty();
```

to erase the old one and render the new one but doesn´t work

Comment: map is not a valid selector for a div, what are you trying to do? Please provide more information.

Comment: What is map here? did you mean map tag or it is id or class?If you want to remove the map showed in div , then you have to empty the div

Comment: Please add the code where **map** is defined to clarify the selector needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('map').remove();
```

If you want to remove the old map and make a new one, just remove the old map.

Even better, do this

```
$(".youMapContainer").empty()
```

Comment: Thanks  Incluiding the following funtion into the funtion who render the map;

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying JQuery:

```
$("#map").html("");
```

Vanilla:

```
function clearTheDiv()
{
    document.getElementById("yourDivIdHere").innerHTML = "";
}
```

And then call "clearTheDiv();" in HTML.

Comment: And make sure the div has "map" as the ID. Or if you're making it a class called "map", then the selector would be $(".map")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Using clearTheDiv()

```
function traza_mapa() {     // function to render the map
    function clearTheDiv()
    {
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "";
    };
    clearTheDiv();
 ......
```